# wxMaxima: treat division as multiplication (gather overall divisions as multiplicative factor)

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

I'm wondering if there is any way to tell Maxima to return

```
1/2*x
```

instead of

```
x/2
```

I'm trying to handle u-substitutions using `changevar` however, it's returning expressions like:

```
\frac{\int \cos{u} \de{u}}{5}
```

whereas I'd like to have it display as

```
\frac{1}{5} \int \cos(u) \de{u}
```

or

```
\int \cos(u) \frac{1}{5} \de{u}
```

Is this possible? If so, any suggestions as to where to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the display option `pfeformat` has the effect you want. By default it's false. Here's what I get when it is enabled:

```
(%i2) pfeformat: true $

(%i3) 'integrate(cos(u),u)/5;
                              /
                              [
(%o3)                   (1/5) I cos(u) du
                              ]
                              /
(%i4) tex(%);
$${{1}\over{5}}\,\int {\cos u}{\;du}$$
```

The internal form of the expression is the same -- you can call `?print` to see what it is -- and `pfeformat` just changes the way it's displayed.

Comment: Thanks Robert! I'll give this a try -- looks like exactly what I was hoping to find :)  Thanks for always taking the time to help!